# Фильтры в Angular ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Мне нужно чтобы в таблице была одна колонка - "Ошибки", и в ячейке были вместе `id` и `name`, например так:

534gfd74 - cannot shut down because a modal dialog is ac...

И чтобы фильтр работал сразу и по id и по name.

Вопрос: как объединить несколько колонок в одну, и чтобы фильтр работал по всем объединенным колонкам?

```
$scope.GridOptions = {
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableScrollbars: false,
        enableHorizontalScrollbar: 2,
        enableVerticalScrollbar: 2,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        enableFullRowSelection: true,
        multiSelect: false,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        noUnselect: true,
        columnDefs: [{
            field: 'Errors',
            headerCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/uiGridHeaderCell-Bootstrap',
            filters: [
                {
                    placeholder: 'Название ошибки'
                }
            ],
            cellTemplate: "<div>{{row.entity.Errors.id}}<br />{{row.entity.Errors.error}}</div>",
        }],
        data: [
            { Errors: { id: '453vcfsd8fsd8', name: 'cannot shut down because a modal dialog is active. Close the active dialog and try again.' } },
            { Errors: { id: '534gfd74', name: 'is not a valid file name.' } },
        ]
 };
```

Comment: т.е. сделать так: `data:[{Errors:'ff68s2346 - cannot shut down because a modal dialog...'}]`?

Comment: нет так не получается, потому что фильтр ищет с начала строки т.е. в данном случае получается поиск только по id мне нужно и по name. Можно настроить чтобы фильтр искал по подстроке а не только с начала?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [свойством condition](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/103_filtering#conditon) - которое представляет собой функцию, принимающую искомую строку, и текущий объект и возвращающая `true` если объект подходит и `false` если нет.

Функция может выглядеть так:

```
condition: function(serachTerm, entity) {
  return ~entity.id.indexOf(serachTerm) || ~entity.name.indexOf(serachTerm);
}
```

Рабочий пример:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'uiGridConstants',
    function($scope, $http, uiGridConstants) {
      var today = new Date();
      var nextWeek = new Date();
      nextWeek.setDate(nextWeek.getDate() + 7);

      $scope.highlightFilteredHeader = function(row, rowRenderIndex, col, colRenderIndex) {
        if (col.filters[0].term) {
          return 'header-filtered';
        } else {
          return '';
        }
      };

      $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableScrollbars: false,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        enableFullRowSelection: true,
        multiSelect: false,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        noUnselect: true,
        columnDefs: [{
          field: 'Errors',
          filters: [{
            placeholder: 'Название ошибки',
            condition: function(serachTerm, entity) {
              return ~entity.id.indexOf(serachTerm) || ~entity.name.indexOf(serachTerm);
            }
          }],
          cellTemplate: "<div>{{row.entity.Errors.id}}<br />{{row.entity.Errors.error}}</div>",
        }],
        data: [{
          Errors: {
            id: '453vcfsd8fsd8',
            name: 'cannot shut down because a modal dialog is active. Close the active dialog and try again.'
          }
        }, {
          Errors: {
            id: '534gfd74',
            name: 'is not a valid file name.'
          }
        }, ]
      };
    }
  ])
  .filter('mapGender', function() {
    var genderHash = {
      1: 'male',
      2: 'female'
    };

    return function(input) {
      if (!input) {
        return '';
      } else {
        return genderHash[input];
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
}
.header-filtered {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это то что нужно, спасибо.

Comment: почему-то некоторые символы, например .(точка) не ищет. И все что после точки не ищет. Хотя точка экранируется \.

Comment: @endovitskiiy, в моем пример все ищет, и ничего не экранируется, если вы что-то поменяли - стоит показать что именно и где, возможно даже задать новый вопрос

Comment: я понял почему не искалось, все работает правильно.

Comment: @endovitskiiy, ну хорошо тогда :)